# Passing multiple strings into stylesheet_link_tag

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I know this must have a simple elegant answer, but somehow I can't figure out what it is. I'm trying to pass **multiple stylesheets** into stylesheet_link_tag, and it's coming out wrong.

When I **directly** call `stylesheet_link_tag "aaa", "bbb"`, I get the following:

```
<link href="/assets/aaa.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/bbb.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Great!

The problem is that I have a function in my application helper that takes a **variable**:

```
stylesheet_link_tag(css_includes)
```

If I call it with a **single** value, all seems fine:

```
> css_includes = "aaa"
> stylesheet_link_tag(css_includes)
>>>  <link href="/assets/aaa.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Sweet!

But if I try to pass in **multiple** objects, it doesn't work:

```
> css_includes = "aaa", "bbb"
> stylesheet_link_tag(css_includes)
>>>  <link href="/assets/["aaa", "bbb"].css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

What's the correct syntax here?

Thanks!

Comment: please revise your selected answer since rails might have changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use an each block :

```
<% ["aaa", "bbb"].each do |name| %>
   stylesheet_link_tag(name)
<% end %>
```

However, I don't think this is the Rails way. You should probably include "aaa" and "bbb" in `application.css` with `require` or `import` if you use sass.

Comment: Thanks! That works great. I realize it's not the most "Rails"-y way, but our site uses different css on different pages, and so using `require_tree` in `application.css` seems like it would be overkill, and this seems like a reasonable way to go about  things.

Comment: @isthmuses see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#controller-specific-assets for controller specifix stylesheets ;)

Comment: @FabiandePabian that makes it controller specific, not page specific.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass an array of string to the `stylesheet_link_tag` method

https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/stylesheet_link_tag

```
stylesheet_link_tag "random.styles", "/css/stylish"
# => <link href="/assets/random.styles" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
#    <link href="/css/stylish.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
```